# Graph three columns in Excel as one data point

Tags: excel, plot, time-series

I'm having trouble graphing some data in Excel properly. I have three columns, which are time, name, and value. If I'm just graphing one name, i.e. "speed", my file looks like this

```
time  |  data  |  value
  1   |  speed |   1
  2   |  speed |   2
  3   |  speed |   3
```

When I try to graph this, it thinks speed is three different things, and graphs as speed 1, speed 2 and speed 3. I instead want a straight line with a slope of 1, called speed, so it recognizes that they're all the same data. Ideally, I could add in extra data names such as acceleration, and it would treat all of those the same too.

Comment: Can you remove the ``data`` column and rename ``value`` as ``speed``? That should do it. If you have some other data like ``altitude``, you can put in another column.

Comment: I could try and write some VBA to do it I suppose, I was hoping there was a native way to get Excel to do it for me

Comment: I think you can do it with a pivot table, putting time in the rows, data in the columns and value in the middle bit. Then you can create a pivot chart from the pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2007: Go to insert --> Scatterplot and create the chart type "Scatter with smooth lines".

1. Give a mouse right click on the chart and pick "Select Data" option.
2. Click on <kbd>Add</kbd> series button and place "Series X values" as the range of values in column `Time` and fill in "Series Y values" with the range data on column `Value`.

If you have additional rows with data meaning something else than `speed`, like `acceleration` you can add a second series to make the second line in the graph.

Example:

[image]